# NVIDIA GeForce 630M and Intel HD graphic 3000

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.10

I've got laptop with ::-

Core i5 (2nd Generation) 2450M
 6 GB RAM DDR3
 Mobile Intel HM77 Express
 NVIDIA GeForce 630M 2 GB DDR
 Intel HD graphic 3000

Can anyone help me to installing correct driver for standard Dedicated + Integrated in ubuntu 12.10
I really appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't support to Optimus Technology yet.

But the good new is that: Nvidia is working to it. Until then, your only option is to continue using only the Nvidia driver.
http://www.pcworld.com/article/261874/coming_soon_to_linux_nvidia_optimus_graphics_support.html

Comment: thnxx i wish it come really soon

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee for optimus powered graphics there is only bumblebee available. With this program, you can run some programs with your dedicated graphics card (in this case the geforce)... You can for example run `optirun firefox` within the terminal and Firefox will use this graphics card.

Comment: thnxx i try ...